# STMP Client as Singleton in Azure Functions app

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app that sends out emails using Amazon SES service and to handle send message operations, I created a client and declare it as a singleton in the `Startup.cs` in my Azure app.

Looks like the first message is sent OK but the subsequent ones fail with the following error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
> 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient'

Here's what my client that handles sending messages looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public class SesClient
{

    SmtpClient _client;
    private string _senderEmail;

    public SesClient(string smtpServer, int smtpPort, string amazonSesUserId, string amazonSesPassword, string senderEmail)
    {
        if (_client == null)
        {
            _client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, smtpPort);
            _client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(amazonSesUserId, amazonSesPassword);
            _client.EnableSsl = true;
            _senderEmail = senderEmail;
        }
    }

    public void SendEmailMessage(MailMessage message)
    {
        message.From = new MailAddress(_senderEmail, "John Doe");

        using (_client)
        {
            try
            {
                _client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I create this class as a singleton in the `ConfigureServices()` method of my `Startup.cs` like this:

```
var smtpServer = Configuration["AmazonSes:SMTP_SERVER"];
var smtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["AmazonSes:SMTP_PORT"]);
var sesUserId = Configuration["AmazonSes:USER_ID"];
var sesPassword = Configuration["AmazonSes:USER_PASSWORD"];
var senderEmail = Configuration["MyApp:EMAIL_ADDRESS"];

services.AddSingleton(new SesClient(smtpServer, smtpPort, sesUserId, sesPassword, senderEmail));
```

I thought creating this client as a singleton was the right idea. Is that where the problem is? If not, any idea what may be the problem here?

Comment: add the code where you get it the instance from the service locator, and is it recommended to keep a single instance of SmtpClient ? Im guessing this all depends on how many times this function is called, which we can not tell as there is not enough code. Please add all code to help other understand it consumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you posted, `using(_client)` effectively disposes the SmtpClient after sending the first e-mail, hence the "object disposed" exception. Since it's a singleton, the constructor doesn't get called again.